# BizTalk mapping attributes with value and text

Tags: biztalk

I have source schema with attributes

```
<st>
<inst amt = Us >458.9 </inst> 
</st>
```

I want to map it to get output "Us 458.9" Have anyone idea how to do? 
right know when I link it source and destination schema I only get "US"

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but you should be able to build an [inline XSLT scripting functoid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267807%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) to do the equivalent of the following XSLT:

```
   <xsl:template match="/st">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(inst/@amt, ' ', inst/text())"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: it does not work in my situation . i keep work on that
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.

Use the String Concatenation Functoid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560973.aspx

Comment: in that project every time i pass xml file i have different number I can not specified that string

Comment: A different number of what?  If <inst> loops, the destination would have to loop as well.

Comment: yes i have a loop
i have and every time i have different number 459.8,   65,   78.2,

Comment: Hi User3014489, I think you need to clarify your requirements as both solutions proposed to you should work (or lead to a resolution) based on your question! Provide as much detail as you can to receive more specific help.

Comment: As my original post I have one node in  source schema I have to get output from attribute and right know every time i try to do it I get only "Us' from that attribute I can not get a  number

1. I put scripting functoid on my map
2. choose "inline xslt call Tamplete"
3 when i use a proposed code i can not get anything.

when i use string concatenation I only get "us"

Comment: Let's not over complicate this.  You must link both @amt (attribute) and inst (element) to the String Concatenation Functoid.  Then link from the String Concatenation Functiod to the destination element or attribute.

Comment: One more thing.  The sample above is actually invalid Xml.  Attribute values must be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution and it was very easy. ( i know that right now :)  )

simply when schema has attribute "" in my example and I want to do mapping to get Ccy value in my example us and also i want to get value "458.9"  in my example. All what i have to do is: connect ccy to particular mapping element in destination schema ( that will get for me "us" ) and connect  St from source schema to element in destination schema ( that will map  "458.9" (in my example))